# SQLITE doesnt return requested data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have this function that is supposed to return object by ID from the database. Although there is data by the requested ID, no data is returned. Can some one help me solve this problem.

Code:

```
public ChildRecord getChild(int id) {
        ChildRecord child = null;
        Log.v("--", "success13s ");
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM child " + "WHERE childID="
                + id, null);
        Log.v("--", "success1 2");
        if (c != null)
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    int childid = c.getInt(0);
                    String parent1 = c.getString(1);
                    String parent2 = c.getString(2);
                    String name = c.getString(3);
                    String dob = c.getString(4);
                    int gender = c.getInt(5);
                    String height = c.getString(6);
                    String weight = c.getString(7);
                    String etnicity = c.getString(8);
                    int type = c.getInt(9);
                    child = new ChildRecord(childid, name, dob, gender, height,
                            weight, etnicity, type, parent1, parent2);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        Log.v("--", "success1 ");
        return child;
    }
```

The problem is at the line

```
Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM child " + "WHERE childID="
                    + id, null);
```

Comment: What value does `id` have at that line?  Does that value exist in the table?

Comment: yes, but Im trying to figure out there is something else wrong..

Comment: What is the type of `childID` in the database? Implicit type conversion (e.g. from type `blob` to `int`) can result in unexpected results.

Comment: That was a question.  What value does `id` have at that line?

Comment: What results do you get, if you remove the `WHERE` clause? Is the expected row part of the result set. Aside from implicit type conversion I can't think of any issues (assuming that id exists in the table). Did you check the range of `int` in Java vs SQLite vs the actual value of `id`.

Comment: @DarkoPetkovski Your code is correct; there is no such record in this database. Why do you think that that value exists?

Answer (score 0):

I want to make this clear first, if you have "child" table with "childID" columns of integer and have data by the id you pass in. There's no thing wrong with the query string.

Then you should check:

1. Are you referring the "right" database
2. Try to execute this query in SQLite DB manager and see if this gives results.
3. If you have results in SQLite DB manager but you don't get any results in your codes. The problem must be from your "database" object.

Please try and tell me your result.